# How can I add the sub uiscrollview inside the uiscrollview with opposite scrolling direction?

Tags: swift

I want to add the sub uiscrollview inside uiscrollview where both scrollview have scrolling in opposite direction.
I used two UIView in the main uiscrollview.
And when inner scrollview is scrolled the main scrollview should be hide.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the answer, 
Inside my UIView is drag the 10 uibutton and then I embedded all buttons inside the stack view and set all the constraints of stackview.

Comment: It is always better to put a reference to you found answer, in case anyone else end up searching your question.